# Запуск программ на виндовс подсистеме линукс

Tags: windows, ubuntu

при попытке запуска программы с дистрибутива ubuntu выдает ошибку

```
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(ghb:2948): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Comment: Как много подробностей. А можно ещё меньше?

Comment: Что вас интересует?

Comment: Версия ОС, название проги, версия wine, способ запуска?

Comment: А, стоп. Ты наоборот что ли запускаешь?

Comment: Windows 10 64 bit последнее обновление

Comment: Я не очень внимательно слежу за новостями про прослойку, но вроде как была заявлена возможность запуска консольных прог. Про гуи чё-то не припомню.

Answer (score 0):

Для запуска графических приложений линукс на подсистеме необходимо установить и запустить приложение Xming, в консоли DISPLAY=:0 programm